# How can I calculate the NoOfDays label correctly that will be displayed on the Confirm aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-state

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace XEx08Reservation
{
    public partial class Request : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private string currentDate = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
        private string currentYear = DateTime.Today.Year.ToString();


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                // set copyright year no matter what
                lblYear.Text = currentYear;

                // display saved reservation data if there is any
                if (Session["Reservation"] != null)
                {
                    DisplayReservation();
                }
                else  {
                    // otherwise, set default values
                    txtArrivalDate.Text = currentDate;
                    rdoKing.Checked = true;
                }   
            }
        }

        private void DisplayReservation()
        {
            Reservation reservation = (Reservation)Session["Reservation"];

            txtArrivalDate.Text = reservation.ArrivalDate.ToShortDateString();
            txtDepartureDate.Text = reservation.DepartureDate.ToShortDateString();
            ddlNoOfPeople.SelectedValue = reservation.NoOfPeople.ToString();

            if (reservation.BedType == "King")
                rdoKing.Checked = true;
            else if (reservation.BedType == "Two Queens")
                rdoDouble.Checked = true;
            else
                rdoSingle.Checked = true;

            txtSpecialRequests.Text = reservation.SpecialRequests;
            txtFirstName.Text = reservation.FirstName;
            txtLastName.Text = reservation.LastName;
            txtEmail.Text = reservation.Email;
            txtPhone.Text = reservation.Phone;
            ddlPreferredMethod.SelectedValue = reservation.PreferredMethod;
        }

        protected void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtArrivalDate.Text = currentDate;
            txtDepartureDate.Text = "";
            ddlNoOfPeople.SelectedIndex = -1;
            rdoKing.Checked = true;
            rdoDouble.Checked = false;
            rdoSingle.Checked = false;
            txtSpecialRequests.Text = "";
            txtFirstName.Text = "";
            txtLastName.Text = "";
            txtEmail.Text = "";
            txtPhone.Text = "";
            ddlPreferredMethod.SelectedIndex = 0;
            lblMessage.Text = "";
        }

        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            Reservation reservation = new Reservation();
            reservation.ArrivalDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtArrivalDate.Text);
            reservation.DepartureDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDepartureDate.Text);
            TimeSpan tsDuration = reservation.DepartureDate - reservation.ArrivalDate;
            reservation.NoOfDays = Convert.ToInt32(tsDuration);
            tsDuration.Days.ToString();
            reservation.NoOfPeople = Convert.ToInt32(ddlNoOfPeople.SelectedValue);
            reservation.PreferredMethod = Convert.ToString(ddlPreferredMethod.SelectedValue);

            if (rdoKing.Checked) reservation.BedType = "King";
            else reservation.BedType = "Double Double";

            reservation.SpecialRequests = txtSpecialRequests.Text;
            reservation.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
            reservation.LastName = txtLastName.Text;
            reservation.Email = txtEmail.Text;
            reservation.Phone = txtPhone.Text;

            Session["Reservation"] = reservation;
            Response.Redirect("Confirm.aspx");

        }
    }
}
```

Hello Everyone,

I have web application in which I am initializing a new reservation object and then set it properties based on the values the user enters on the form; however, I am having trouble correctly calculating the total numbers of days between the `ArrivalDate` and the `DepartureDate` that will eventually be displayed in a label on the `Confirm.aspx` page. Can someone help me?

Comment: Please read this guide for how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then modify the question as described in the guide. It may take some time to read the guide and make the modifications, but it will help you to get better answers and you may discover the answer while revising the question. As an example of a modification that would help, if your question is regarding `days(DepartureDate - ArrivalDate)`, it's very unlikely that the minimal example will contain `King`, `Two Queens` or `reservation.Phone`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **Subtract** to find the diff and use the days property to get the exact number of days.

```
var ArrivalDate = DateTime.Parse( "09 Aug 2008");
var DepartureDate = DateTime.Parse("03 Aug 2009");
var days = DepartureDate.Subtract(ArrivalDate).Days;
```

I over looked your code. you are actually doing close to the above. Please let me know what is the exact issue. It looks like it is not just the date calculation. More like conversion from datetime from string. If this is what you are facing, Use the below suggesions

1. Follow the current culture while getting user inputs
2. Use the same culture to convert date from the string